# Iterate and apply XSLT identity transformation to directory of documents?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a folder with HTML files  which look more or less like this:

```
<div id="d10e3019" class="content">
   <h1>header</h1>
   <div class="adv">
      <div class="warn">
         <img width="60px" height="20px" src="img/warn.png" alt="WARNING"></img>
         <p class="cause">gfgfg!</p>
         <p>⇒  Thgfh</p>
         <p class="step">⇔ 
            <span class="emphasis">hgfh
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

They all have `<div id="someId" class="content">` as root element and then just various HTML markup.

I need to change all of the `src` attributes in the `img` tags of each document to look like this:

```
<img width="60px" height="20px" src="http://server.com/{$nameOfTheCurtentFolder}/img/warn.png" alt="WARNING"></img>
```

and wrap the new output in another `div` with a new child element. The rest of the document needs to be exactly the same.

I tried this stylesheet, but with this stylesheet only the text nodes get written in the output document (while generating the new `div` element works):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version='2.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:fn='http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions' exclude-result-prefixes='xsl xs fn' xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="files" select="collection('./output?select=*.html')"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="$files">
            <xsl:variable name="fileName" select="tokenize(base-uri(), '/')[last()]"/>
            <xsl:result-document method="xhtml" href="new/{$fileName}">
                <div>
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="pubs"/>
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </div>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@src">
        <xsl:variable name="nameOfTheCurtentFolder" select="tokenize(base-uri(), '/')[last()-2]"/>
        <xsl:text>http://server.com/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$nameOfTheCurtentFolder"/>
        <xsl:text>/output/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output looks like this:

```
              <div>
                 <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="pubs"/>
                  headergfgfg!⇒  Thgfhhgfh
              </div>
```

This is a follow-up to my earlier question, [Change attribute value without creating new output document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779464/change-attribute-value-without-creating-new-output-document)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your stylesheet is missing the *identity transform* template:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

In addition, in order to change the value of an attribute, you need to recreate it first:

```
<xsl:template match="@src">
    <xsl:attribute name="src">
        <xsl:variable name="nameOfTheCurtentFolder" select="tokenize(base-uri(), '/')[last()-2]"/>
        <xsl:text>http://server.com/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$nameOfTheCurtentFolder"/>
        <xsl:text>/output/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Finally, the HTML document to be processed must also be a well-formed XML; the provided example is not.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I'll just never understand how copying works in XSLT. How come the identity transform is only applied to the contents of the files and not to the document that I use to start the transformation (which also has some content)?

Comment: It's because your first template, that matches the root of the "real" input XML, intervenes and changes the context to `$files`. So no templates are ever applied to the children of `/`.

Answer (score 2):

Got it to work, too, only 5 minutes too late (compared with michael.hor257k):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version='2.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:fn='http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions' exclude-result-prefixes='xsl xs fn' xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:param name="files" select="collection('./output/*.xml')"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="$files">
            <xsl:variable name="fileName" select="tokenize(base-uri(), '/')[last()]"/>
            <xsl:result-document method="xhtml" href="new/{$fileName}">
                <div>
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="pubs"/>
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </div>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@src">
        <xsl:attribute name="src">
            <xsl:variable name="nameOfTheCurtentFolder" select="tokenize(base-uri(), '/')[last()-2]"/>
            <xsl:text>http://server.com/</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$nameOfTheCurtentFolder"/>
            <xsl:text>/output/</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

**General Solution**

XSLT has no standard way to iterate over directories of files.  You are expected to apply XSLT via external control to achieve such an effect.  A Saxon extension  to the `collection()` function, however, which can do this...

### Iterating over input documents and applying identify transformation

```
The following XSLT will apply an adjusted identity transformation to all `$inSubdirName` HTML files and place the results in `$outSubdirName`:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version='2.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="inSubdirName" select="'in'"/>
  <xsl:param name="outSubdirName" select="'out'"/>

  <!-- Driver for each file in inSubdirName -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="collection(concat($inSubdirName, '/?select=*.html'))">
      <xsl:variable name="inFileName" select="base-uri()"/>
      <xsl:variable name="outFileName"
                    select="concat($outSubdirName, '/',
                            tokenize(base-uri(), '/')[last()])"/>
      <xsl:message select="concat('Transforming from ',
                           $inFileName, ' to ', $outFileName)"/>
      <xsl:result-document method="xhtml" href="{$outFileName}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Identity transform overrides -->
  <xsl:template match="/div">
    <div xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
      <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="pubs"/>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@src">
    <xsl:attribute name="src">
      <xsl:variable name="nameOfTheCurrentFolder"
                    select="tokenize(base-uri(), '/')[last()-2]"/>
      <xsl:text>http://server.com/</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$nameOfTheCurrentFolder"/>
      <xsl:text>/output/</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied to input HTML files such as you provided, corrected to be well-formed:**

```
<div id="d10e3019" class="content">
   <h1>header 1</h1>
   <div class="adv">
      <div class="warn">
         <img width="60px" height="20px" src="img/warn.png" alt="WARNING"></img>
         <p class="cause">gfgfg!</p>
         <p>⇒  Thgfh</p>
         <p class="step">⇔ 
            <span class="emphasis">hgfh</span>
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Will transform them with the new `@src` attribute and the new `div` and `h:selectBooleanCheckbox` child element,**

```
<div xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
   <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="pubs"></h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
   <div id="d10e3019" class="content">
      <h1>header 1</h1>
      <div class="adv">
         <div class="warn">
            <img width="60px" height="20px" src="http://server.com/xslt/output/img/warn.png" alt="WARNING"></img>
            <p class="cause">gfgfg!</p>
            <p>⇒  Thgfh</p>
            <p class="step">⇔ 

               <span class="emphasis">hgfh</span>
            </p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**as requested**, with a declaration added for the `h` namespace prefix to ensure that the output is well-formed.

Note also these improvements to your original XSLT:

- Input and output directories are parameterized.
- The driver XSLT that does iteration is fully isolated from the
  identity transformation XSLT templates which are responsible for
  applying changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I chose michael.hor257k's answer because it's a little less verbose.

Comment: No problem -- @michael.hor257k's answers are always excellent.  Good luck.